# REGEX Help for alpha dot alpha pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following REGEX that checks for a pattern like (alpha and decimals only):

```
abc.def
abc.def.ghi
```

The pattern is:

```
^[a-zA-Z.]*$
```

What I need to do is make sure there are no leading or trailing decimals.  So something like this would be illegal:

```
.abc.def
abc.def.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z] +\.)+[a-zA-Z] +$
```

I test against your example and it works.

Comment: Close.  I can only allow alpha, no numbers.  Can you adjust and I'll test again?

Comment: That worked.  I'll accept who ever posts it first.  Or if Tiago edits his.